# Create an installer in Java

Tags: java, installation

I want to create an installer using Java that install at first MySQL. The user tape at first the password of root user. Then the installer copy jar file into program files and create shortcut on desktop.

So my question how to install MySQL automatic via Java. Is there any way??

Thanks in advance.

best regards,

Ali

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try to perform a 'private' ad-hoc MySQL installation that is only used by your application: that means you will have to copy the binaries (please note they are different for each platform) plus some custom configuration files to a 'mysql' subdirectory of your programs' main directory.

I can assure you it won't be easy and fast to do. You have to struggle a bit making it work under each platform. This kind of stuff is always a bit tricky.

If you prefer to install MySQL in a system-wide manner (as a service, using the provided install package) you'll have to embed the package into your setup program and then use the proper operating system commands to install it. That would be different on each platform, and under Linux you'll have to install the proper package for each distro. Messy.

You can look at some commercial solutions for making Java install programs. See install4j for example.

Shipping MySQL with your Java application is not so easy. Are you sure you need MySQL, and you cannot use some simpler alternatives, like **sqlite**? If you choose sqlite, there are some 100% java solutions, and that means no difference between platforms and easy deploy of your application.

Think about it, listening to this simple advice can make you save 14-15 hours of work and debugging (with always some possibility of failure, because complex installers do fail).

Comment: At first, I'll create a version that run on Windows then one for Linux and I'll try to move my DB to sqlite.

Answer (score 3):

Depends on the platforms you want to install onto. Basically if you know how to do it via the command line, then you can write a shell script that is executed from Java, or a series of command line statements that are executed from Java to do it.

Since you mention root user, I'm guessing some flavor of linux? Doesn't MySQL already have ways of doing this that come with the installers and/or binary distributions?

Comment: Good answer, as it answers the question, but all of this is a bit messy. Just imagine a script written by some casual programmer installing mysql onto a system, system-wide. I feel this is not the way. There are so many differences between the systems, so many ways this stuff can go wrong (MySQL is already installed, wrong CPU architecture, etc...). I don't recommend it.

Comment: @Giacomo - well, I agree, but that's you and me assuming that he'd do it like us. Zengr wants to do it in Java - more power to him. Maybe there's some strange technical requirement for him to do it this way that he doesn't mention.

Answer (score 3):

This write-up might help you in creating a java installer: [Convert Java to EXE (also has information about other platforms)](http://www.excelsior-usa.com/articles/java-to-exe.html)

But, before going for that, I would like to ask you, why do you want o bundle MySQL with your java app? The recommended way, if you want a DBMS bundled in your app can be:

1. Ask the user the install MySQL him self. You app will use it.
2. Use [SqLite](http://www.sqlite.org/) (embedded RDBMS). Or even simpler, [Berkley DB](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/database/berkeleydb/overview/index.html) for a Key-value store. This approach will be super light and no installation needed.